# Display result from controller to the view in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a young developer in asp.net mvc, now I'm trying to do a simple calculator that calculate the value that user input.

This is my model of mvc:

```
public class MoneyInstallments
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="The price is required.")]
    public double price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The duration is required.")]
    public int duration { get; set; }

    public double interestRate = 0.029;
    public double total_interest { get; set; }
    public double total_money { get; set; }
    public double total_money_month { get; set; }

}
```

The controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection frm)
{
        string price_str = frm["price"].ToString();
        string duration_str = frm["duration"].ToString();
        double price;
        double duration;

        try
        {
            price = Convert.ToDouble(price_str);
            duration = Convert.ToDouble(duration_str);
            double interestRate = 0.029;
            double total_interest = interestRate * duration;
            double total_money = total_interest + price;
            double total_money_month = total_money / duration;

        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Response.Write("Unable to caculate"+price_str);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Response.Write("Unable to caculate" + price_str);
        }


        return View();
    }
```

The views :

```
  <% Html.BeginForm(); %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Money Information</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Price:</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.price, new { id = "price", name = "price"})%> <!-- user can type only 50 char of the string -->
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.price)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Interest per month</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>2.9%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Duration</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.duration, new {id="duration", name="duration"}) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.duration) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Calculate"id="btnCalculate"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Monthly Pay is</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><div id="result"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

I want to display the total_money_month from my controller to the  in my views, but I have know idea about that. Anyone can tell me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass values to the view by using your ViewBag in your controller:

```
ViewBag.MonthlyTotal = total_money_month; 
return View();
```

Then in your view, you can display it:

```
@ViewBag.MonthlyTotal
```

**Edit:**

To use ViewData instead:

Controller:

```
 ViewData["MonthlyTotal"] = total_money_month; 
 return View();
```

View-

```
<%= ViewData["MonthlyTotal"]  %>
```

Comment: Using ViewBag have error : It does not contain in my current context.

Comment: Are you using MVC3? If not, you can use ViewData instead.

Comment: I want to make my form submit without refresh page, what should I do? I'm pretty new in ajax and jquery.